# Самая технологичная библиотека PHP для работы с MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы посмотреть на очень "крутой" пример реализации CRUD на языке PHP с использованием всех допустимых функций ООП. Встречались ли Вам такие?

Вопрос возник не с проста... Одни складывают 2+2 при помощи Laravel, а другие создают класс с мощным названием PHPCmsEngineClass и по старинке процедуры в __construct используют. Как следствие, чтобы учиться и писать грамотный код, его необходимо буквально собирать по крупицам. Встретил хорошую реализацию функции - адаптировал под свои нужды и т.п.
В общем буду рад интересным решениями.
P.S.: "Монстров" индустрии не предлагайте. Я имею ввиду библиотеки как Laravel, Yii и им подобных. Они очень велики и касаются всех аспектов работы языка, а не только в MySQL. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У каждого своё предпочтение в том, какой кол хорошо и качественно написан, а какой нет. Самостоятельно просмотрите реализацию упомянутых библиотек или framework и решите что вам больше подходит на текущий момент.

Answer (score 2):

Какая то у вас лютая каша. Laravel и Yii это фреймворки.

> > Хотелось бы посмотреть на очень "крутой" пример реализации CRUD на языке PHP с использованием всех допустимых функций ООП

Наверное вы хотели увидеть ORM или ActiveRecord, если уже о библиотеках для работы с sql. Тогда посмотрите Doctrine2, Eloquent ORM, Propel